# Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_timezone_offset()?

Tags: php

I am keep getting this error on my PHP page. I thought the error was because of the version of the php installed on my server but when i checked it with

```
 <?php
echo "Version is: " . phpversion();
?>
```

the PHP version is  5.2.17.

my current code is:

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <select name="timezone2" id="timezone2" class="timezone2">
    <option value="Pacific/Midway">(GMT-11:00) Midway Island, Samoa</option>
    <option value="America/Adak">(GMT-10:00) Hawaii-Aleutian</option>
    .. snip ..
</select>
  <select name="timezone1" id="timezone1" class="timezone1">
    <option value="Pacific/Midway">(GMT-11:00) Midway Island, Samoa</option>
    <option value="America/Adak">(GMT-10:00) Hawaii-Aleutian</option>
    .. snip ..
  </select>
<input type="submit" value="send"> </input>

</form>


<?php
if( isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //be sure to validate and clean your variables
    $timezone1 = htmlentities($_POST['timezone1']);
    $timezone2 = htmlentities($_POST['timezone2']);

    //then you can use them in a PHP function. 
    function get_timezone_offset( $origin_tz, $remote_tz ) {
    $timezone1 = new DateTimeZone( $origin_tz );
    $timezone2 = new DateTimeZone( $remote_tz );

    $datetime1 = new DateTime("now", $timezone1);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime("now", $timezone2);

    $offset = $timezone1->getOffset($datetime1) - $timezone2->getOffset($datetime2);
    return $offset;
}
}

$offset = get_timezone_offset('datetime1', 'datetime2');

echo $offset/3600;
?>
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong here!

could someone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 5):

You are defining the function `get_timezone_offset()`  only if `$_POST['submit']` is set. But you are calling `get_timezone_offset()` everytime. Also if `$_POST['submit']` is not set.

Comment: That isn't a default PHP language function `get_timezone_offset`, that's the same mistake as in the OP's code. It's http://php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-offset-get.php

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ The OP is defining `get_timezone_offset` in his code! Look twice!

Comment: Right. It's a user defines function and he is calling this function every time, but he is defining the function only if $_POST['submit'] is set. This is his mistake. If $_POST['submit'] sin't set he calls the function anyway and produces the shown error.

Comment: @Cromax, Okay, but when i change '$offset = get_timezone_offset('datetime1', 'datetime2');' to '$offset = get_timezone_offset;' all i get on my page is a 0. any idea of what I am doing wrong there?

Comment: @SimonPresto: It's different for different inputs, from what I can see.

Comment: @Simon Presto: if you are declaring the function in the if block, you should call the function in the if block too. Think about what happens if $_POST['submit'] is not set. In this case your function isn't declared but you are calling it.